# replacing value of XML file in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I load an XML document using XMLHTTPRequest in my js file. the XML file is like below:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RMFSFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Host>www.example.com</Host>
  <Port>8888</Port>   
  <Uri>www.example.com</Uri>
<Path>
     <HD>
        <UNC>path1</UNC>
    </HD>
    <SD>
       <UNC>path2</UNC>
    </SD>
</Path>
```

I am now trying to first select Path1, and Path2 nodes, and then **switch** the value of **path1** with the value of **path2**.
I select the nodes like below:

```
 var firstNode = xmlFile.querySelector('Path>HD>UNC'); \\ I can get the node successfully. 
 var secondNode= xml.querySelector('Path>SD>UNC');  \\ I can get the node successfully.
```

**However**, when I try to replace the values by using the following code:

```
    xmlFile.replaceChild(secondNode,firstNode) // secondNode, is the new value for first node.
```

I get an error says,"An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist".
Any Idea where I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of swapping the nodes, just swap their contents like below:

```
 var firstValue =xmlFile.querySelector('Path>HD>UNC').textContent;                                    
 var secondValue= xmlFile.querySelector('Path>HD>UNC').textContent;

 firstValue.textContent = secondValue;

 secondValue.textContent = firstValue ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`replaceChild` really does mean replace **child** not great-grandchild.

You need to replace `xmlFile` with the parent node of the element you are replacing.